# regex to find all files in a string

Tags: python

I have a string as below:

```
56451   -rw-                1  Aug 10 2023 08:54:53 +00:00  .callhome
56482   -rw-            14846   Jul 4 2023 23:02:34 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC-info.txt
56481   -rw-         68333650   Jul 4 2023 23:02:28 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz
233859  -rw-             9508   Jul 4 2023 17:47:54 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-174745-UTC-info.txt
56480   -rw-         61744940   Jul 4 2023 17:47:48 +00:00  Router-
56450   drwx             4096  Jun 18 2023 06:17:45 +00:00  modules
```

I need a regex to find the file names. It should have extension of `tar.gz`

Code I started with:

```
    matches = re.finditer("(\w+)\s+(\d+)", file_string)
    for match in matches:
        filenames.append(match.group(1))
```

Comment: nothing in your string contains `core.gz`

Comment: corrected the typo

Comment: `(\S+\.tar\.gz)$` ...?

Comment: Can files contain spaces? Can directories contain `.tar.gz`? Do all relevant files follow the naming schema from your example?

Comment: That string looks like the output of some `ls` invocation. Can't you just use `ls *.tar.gz` instead? Or get the directory listing directly in Python, e.g. using [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)?

Answer (score 0):

if that string is in such a format:

```
data ="""
    56451   -rw-                1  Aug 10 2023 08:54:53 +00:00  .callhome
    56482   -rw-            14846   Jul 4 2023 23:02:34 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC-info.txt
    56481   -rw-         68333650   Jul 4 2023 23:02:28 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz
    233859  -rw-             9508   Jul 4 2023 17:47:54 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-174745-UTC-info.txt
    56480   -rw-         61744940   Jul 4 2023 17:47:48 +00:00  Router-
    56450   drwx             4096  Jun 18 2023 06:17:45 +00:00  modules
    """
```

I would first split the string with the space, and get only the strings inside that have a `extension`

```
import re
file_paths = [f for f in data.split(" ") if re.match(r'^[\w,\s-]+\.[A-Za-z]{1,}$', f)]

# if you are looking for a specific extension like .tar.gz:
regex_pattern = r'^[\w,\s-]+\.tar\.gz$'
file_paths = [f for f in data.split(" ") if re.match(regex_pattern, f)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I might do it with [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

```py
import re

s = """56451   -rw-                1  Aug 10 2023 08:54:53 +00:00  .callhome
56482   -rw-            14846   Jul 4 2023 23:02:34 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC-info.txt
56481   -rw-         68333650   Jul 4 2023 23:02:28 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz
233859  -rw-             9508   Jul 4 2023 17:47:54 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-174745-UTC-info.txt
56480   -rw-         61744940   Jul 4 2023 17:47:48 +00:00  Router-
56450   drwx             4096  Jun 18 2023 06:17:45 +00:00  modules"""

pattern = re.compile(r"\s+([-_A-Za-z0-9]+?\.tar\.gz)(?:$|\n)")
pattern.findall(s)
```

This results in a list of strings matching `pattern`:

```
['Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz']
```

The `(?:$|\n)` matches the end of the line or the end of the string, to make sure we are only looking at the things at the end of each line. It's probably overkill, to be honest. Note also that you might want to add other characters to allowable filenames inside the square brackets, e.g. a literal dot, or plus sign. (To my knowledge, there's no simple regex that will allow all possible filename characters.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are are sure that filenames do not contain spaces, then just split the whole text into tokens, then select the filenames from there:

```py
found = [
    token
    for token in file_string.split()
    if token.endswith(".tar.gz")
]
print(found)
```

Output:

```py
['Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz']
```

If filenames might contain spaces, we can use regular expression:

```py
import re

file_string = """56451   -rw-                1  Aug 10 2023 08:54:53 +00:00  .callhome
56482   -rw-            14846   Jul 4 2023 23:02:34 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC-info.txt
56481   -rw-         68333650   Jul 4 2023 23:02:28 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-230220-UTC.tar.gz
233859  -rw-             9508   Jul 4 2023 17:47:54 +00:00  Router-system-report_20230704-174745-UTC-info.txt
56480   -rw-         61744940   Jul 4 2023 17:47:48 +00:00  Router-
56450   drwx             4096  Jun 18 2023 06:17:45 +00:00  modules
"""

pattern = re.compile(
    r"""
    ^
    (              # Start grouping the 8 columns before filename
    [^\s]+         # Each column starts with non space chars
    \s+            # Follows by a number of white spaces
    ){8}           # there are 8 columns before the filename
    (.+\.tar\.gz)  # The filename, which might include spaces
    $
    """,
    re.VERBOSE,
)

found = []
for line in file_string.splitlines():
    matched = pattern.match(line)
    if matched:
        found.append(matched.group(2))
print(found)
```

The output is the same as before. Here are a few notes

- I use `re.compile(..., re.VERBOSE)` which allows for embedded comments. I highly recommend `re.VERBOSE`, especially for moderate to complex regular expressions
- There are 2 groups in each match. The first contains the 8 columns before the file name, the second contains the filename
- Instead of dealing with multi-line string, I prefer to work with each line separately because it is easier that way.